# Wordpress plugin does not redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

I am creating a plugin for woocommerce which sends a POST to a service then with response should redirect to another url

```
            $response = json_decode($result, true);

            if ($response != null || $response != "") {
                $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

                // TODO Check when we use other cryptocurrency
               // header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");
                header('Location: ' . $response['data']['url']."?cryptoCurrency=BTC", true, 301);
                exit();
            }
```

Locally this redirect works, but in production the request does not redirect. I receive a generic error `syntaxerror: unexpected token < in Json at position 0` and a response with OPTIONS 204 as response, another with 301 and other with 200 (image link below).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgswR.jpg

I suppose there's something related to the server, but I really don't know what could it be.

Edit: the result has a valid url. It just doesn't redirect. In a response I am able to get the url and access via browser

Comment: May be $result has wrong syntax for json. Please check your json online

Comment: Khushboo, the result has this url. It just doesn't redirect. In a response I am able to get the url and access via browser.

Comment: Could you please add the response in your question?

Comment: Khushboo, this is a var_dump of response https://gist.github.com/Jonss/3fa656b07eaf655cfe4c103fb1400f97

Answer (score 0):

Khushboo, I fixed.

The problem was there's code above this redirect. So I put what was after code before it, then redirect like this:

```
            if($response != null || $response != "") {
               $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

               $checkout_url = $response['data']['url'] . "?cryptoCurrency=BTC";

               return array(
                 'result' => 'success',
                 'redirect' => $checkout_url
               );
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The it solved. Just like magic =((((